# Detecting out of date ITurnBasedMatch on Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

I am writing a Turn-Based multiplayer Android game using the Google Play API.

Thinking ahead to future versions of the app, I realize I may need to change the format of my [Byte Data Blob](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatch.html#getData()) that gets passed around by the [ITurnBasedMatch](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatch.html) object.

And if I change the blob format, I will need to detect at runtime which version of the blob data I have received, so that it can be properly deserialized without crashing. Or at the least, throw up an error message and let the user know the match is no longer valid.

Is there anything built into the Google Play library that I could set/get a version number for the blob data, *prior* to deserializing it?

For reference here is the implementation of the callback function which Google-Play uses to notify the game that match data has changed:

```
    public void OnTurnBasedMatchReceived(ITurnBasedMatch match)
    {
        // This happens when the other player makes a move in a match we are
        // involved in (although not nessessarily playing right now).
        OnUpdateMatchInfoRecieved(match);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eneded up using the Serializable attribute built into C#. I chose this route, as it gracefully handles issues around [versioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752(v=vs.110).aspx).

More information can be found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific in the play library to indicate a version number.  Typically this is handled in the serialization of the data by the application.  One really nice solution is Flatbuffers: http://google.github.io/flatbuffers/

There is a nice video summary at http://youtu.be/iQTxMkSJ1dQ.

In the mean time, is it possible to check the first couple bytes of the buffer and determine the version?

For example, if your newer version always wrote out V.x where V. are the ASCII characters V and period, and x is the version number of your serialization.  This way you can safely determine if the buffer does not start with V. then it is an old version, and you should use the old deserialization logic.